# System Main thread on Single Core Processor

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, processor

I apologize if this question is a bit out there, but it seems interesting to me and I cannot find any good answer from my research. I know that an operating system has a main system thread that does tasks such as manage other threads, but how exactly does this work on a single-core processor that is not hyperthreaded? In my thinking, it wouldn't be possible to give control to another thread that an application was using, as this would cause the system thread to block. But obviously it is possible, so how exactly does it work? I have thought of the system thread incorporating the work of the other threads into its own, but that just seem like it would be a horrible idea to me.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_(computing)

Comment: Having a thousands running threads is pretty normal.  So of course this isn't exclusive to a single core processor.  The ability to suspend a thread to allow another one to run is a standard operating system feature.  This is covered in any introductory book on operating system design, required reading for any programmer.

Comment: @SLaks that was an interesting page and I learned quite a few things from it, thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant I'll have to check that out and just read through one. Do you have any suggestion of an online resource that would be good? I have found this [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39027/Beginning-Operating-System-Development-Part-One) that seems promising, but other suggestions are always good as well.

Comment: Clearly I suggested you pay a visit to your local library or book store.  Or a class, shouldn't be hard to find around North Carolina State University

Comment: @HansPassant Ahh I always seem to prefer the online resources, but I'll have a look either at the library here or one of the ones there when I get back in the fall. I checked on courses, but unfortunately it would be a couple years before I could even get the prereqs that I need for it. Thanks though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'I know that an operating system has a main system thread that does tasks such as manage other threads' - NO, not in preemptive, multithreaded OS, ie. all effective ones.

After boot time, the OS is only entered by threads upon an 'interrupt'.  There are software interrupts - system calls, and hardware interrupts via drivers, that can change the state of threads.  Between these interrupts, the OS does nothing at all.  No interrupts: the OS does nothing.

I appreciate that this is difficult to grasp, especially with the mostly piss-poor 'Intro to Threads' pages/chapters, but that is how it is.

Be aware that a large pile of stuff re. threads on the web etc. is either inadequate, misleading, over-simplified or actually wrong.  Common wrongness keyphrases: 'time-slice', 'quantum', 'round-robin', 'timer-scheduled'.

Comment: +1 For the characterization of most online documents about threads. Maybe you can provide the inquirer with a good source to start with.

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks for the answer and letting me know about the wrongness in some online articles; almost all of the ones I have read used those terms. I have come to the conclusion that I will have to read up on this to get a better understanding. Please let me know if you have any suggestions of what may be good to read.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that an operating system has a main system thread that does tasks such as manage other threads...

In every operating system I'm familiar with, the scheduler is run by all CPUs when task switching occurs. There is no "main system thread".